# Is there a way to read serialized files using Files.lines in Java 8

Tags: serialization, file-io, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to read a serialized file of objects, but I want to experiment with the funtional programming features of Java 8; however, I kept getting a MalformedInputException. Apparently, Files.lines reads in a Stream<String>, not objects. ([Files class in Oracle Documentation.)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) Thus the malformed input -- it can't handle the serialized characters of the string with the charset it's using.

I normally would use an ObjectInputStream, but I was in the mood to experiment with something new. Is there something I'm missing in Java 8 that allows reading from serialized files using streams in the context of lambdas?

If you're interested, here's an attempt I made before learning that it's creating a Stream<String> (WordDefinitions.dat is a serialized file holding custom data class objects from a class I called Definition -- basically just strings for the experiment):

```
List<Definition> defsList =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("WordDefinitions.dat")) 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I even tried an explicit cast:

```
List<String> defsList =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("WordDefinitions.dat"))
        .map(item -> {
            Definition temp = (Definition)item;
            return temp.toString();
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. There is no equivalent of Files.lines() that would return a Stream<Object>. I see 2 main reasons for that: 1. saving serialized objects in a file is not common, and shouldbe avoided IMO (prefer a more long-term, open and maintainable solution such as JSON or XML), 2. When saving objects to a file using serialization, serializing a single List or Set of objects is much easier.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality to convert an `ObjectInputStream` into a `Stream<Object>` and generally, these feature don’t play well together. Most notably, `ObjectInputStream` doesn’t offer any way to recognize whether more objects are available, i.e. whether the end of stream has been reached.

Still, you can create a stream using the following method:

```
public static Stream<Object> fromFile(File f) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is=new FileInputStream(f);
    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(is);
        return StreamSupport.stream(
        new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<Object>(Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED) {
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Object> action) {
                try {
                    action.accept(ois.readObject());
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    throw new NoClassDefFoundError(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            @Override public Spliterator<Object> trySplit() { return null; }
        }, false).onClose(() -> { try { ois.close(); }
            catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); } });
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        try(FileInputStream toClose=is) { throw t; }
    }
}
```

As said, this stream doesn’t know its number of objects and thus requires explicit use of `limit` to ensure that no attempt to read past the end is made:

```
File f=File.createTempFile("ser", null);
try(FileOutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(f);
    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os)) {
    oos.writeObject("hello");
    oos.writeObject(42);
    oos.writeObject(Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z"));
    oos.flush();
}
System.out.println(f+": "+f.length()+" bytes");
try(Stream<Object> s=fromFile(f)) {
    s.limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome answer! That helps a lot! It will take me a while to learn the new concepts in there, but i can't wait to tackle them! I had heard of Spliterators, but had no ideas what they were or what they were for. Now I have a good reason to look at them more closely. And I had never heard of the StreamSupport class! Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

No. Serialized objects are not lines.

Comment: Yes, I already figured that out, as I showed in the text of my question. JB Nizet answered my question quite well -- "There is no equivalent of Files.lines() that would return a Stream<Object>". Thank you for your time.